# Производительность Q3DScatter

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, производительность

Строю трехмерный график при помощи `QtDataVisualization`.

```
Q3DScatter *scatter = new Q3DScatter;
QScatterDataProxy *proxy = new QScatterDataProxy;
QScatter3DSeries *series = new QScatter3DSeries(proxy);

//...
void addItem(double x, double y, double z){
    QScatterDataItem item;
    item.setX(x);
    item.setY(y);
    item.setZ(z);
    proxy->addItem(item);
}
```

Проблема в том, что метод `addItem` вызывается в параллельном потоке довольно часто. И каждый раз `scatter` обновляется. При большом количестве точек(тысячи) начинаются "фризы". Пока на ум приходи только одно решение, накапливать точки и добавлять сразу сотнями:

```
void addItem(double x, double y, double z){
    static QScatterDataArray items;

    QScatterDataItem item;
    item.setX(x);
    item.setY(y);
    item.setZ(z);

    items.append(item);
    if(items.size() >= 100){
        proxy->addItems(items);
    }
}
```

Как по мне это костыль. Может кто-то знает какую-нибудь опцию или эвент, с которыми можно что-то сделать, чтобы график не обновлялся целиком ради каждой новой точки?

**UPD:**

Исходя из ответа @alexis031182, "красиво" сделать не выйдет. Делаю примерно так:

```
class Scatter : public QWidget{
    QScatterDataProxy *_proxy;
    QScatterDataArray _items;
    int _timerId;
    //...
public:
    Scatter():
        _timer(startTimer(100))
    {}
   //...
protected:
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event){
        if(event->timerId() != _timerId){
            return;
        }
        event->accept();

        if(_items.empty()){ 
            return;
        }

        _proxy->addItems(_items);
        _items.clear();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Проблема в том, что метод addItem вызывается в параллельном потоке
>   довольно часто.

Метод `addItem()` относится к некоему произвольному классу, однако метод `QScatterDataProxy::addItems()`, который вызывается внутри обозначенного, относится уже, если можно так выразиться, к GUI-части. Соответственно, если внутри метода `QScatterDataProxy` нет соответствующей обработки на предмет несоответствия текущего потока главному (а её скорее всего нет), то могут быть различные последствия, включая "фризы" на экране.

Попробуйте вызывать `QScatterDataProxy::addItems()` исключительно в главном потоке. Так как этот метод не является слотом, да и не отмечен как `Q_INVOKABLE`, то придётся завести отдельный кастомный функционал, который будет вставлять собранные данные в прокси-контейнер. Также, как вариант, можно многопоточно накапливать данные в `QScatterDataArray`, а уже в главном потоке считывать их по таймеру.

Ещё один момент, возможно, связан с опечаткой:

```
void addItem(double x, double y, double z){
    static QScatterDataArray items;

    QScatterDataItem item;
    item.setX(x);
    item.setY(y);
    item.setZ(z);

    items.append(item);
    if(items.size() >= 100){
        proxy->addItems(items);
    }
}
```

В коде не очищается `items` после вставки серии точек. Соответственно вторая сотня вставляемых точек будет содержать и первую. Следующая вставка добавит триста точек, вместо новых ста, и т.д.

Что касается вставки точек сериями, то это правильный подход. Об этом также говорится и в [справке](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-data-handling.html) в разделе "Dealing with real-time data". Также там упоминается причина, в виду которой может производиться полная перерисовка графика:

> Due to the unsorted nature of the scatter data, any change in the data
>   window ranges requires all data points to be checked for visibility,
>   which can cause increasing slowdown if data is continually added to
>   the proxy. For the best performance with the scatter graphs, only keep
>   the data you need in the proxy.

Если своими словами, то проседание происходит из-за определения границ видимости поступающих с неотсортированными координатами точек.

Comment: Внимательно посмотрел код, понял что был не прав. Метод `addItem` вызывается в слоте, который дергается из другого потока. Так что все в порядке, `addItem` выполняется в главном потоке.

Comment: Справку почитал. Понял что придется накапливать данные и по таймеру скидывать в прокси